# SqlCommand and error: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Tags: c#, wpf, list, sqlcommand

I've got a little problem. In my program i need a list of SqlCommand objects. So there is a piece of code:

```
List<SqlCommand> commands;
int i = 0;
foreach (string komenda in komendy)
{
    commands.ElementAt<SqlCommand>(i) = new SqlCommand(komenda, dostep());
    i++;
}
```

where komendy is a list of string with command strings and function `dostep()` is returning connection (`SqlConnection` object).

I've got an error: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer for commands.ElementAt< SqlCommand >(i)  and i really don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use LINQ:

```
List<SqlCommand> commands = komendy.Select(x => new SqlCommand(x, dostep())).ToList();
```

With your approach you're missing `commands` initialization

```
List<SqlCommand> commands = new List<SqlCommand>();
```

And you should use `Add` method instead of `ElementAt`:

```
foreach (string komenda in komendy)
{
    commands.Add(new SqlCommand(komenda, dostep()));
}
```

Comment: Oh, i don't know why i forgot about Add function. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

[ElementAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) is a method that returns the object at the specified index in the sequence, you are using it as it was an assignement to add elements to the list.

When using a `List(of Type)`, to add elements to the list you use the [Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) without specifying a precise location. (This is the main job of arrays)
Just use.....

```
 commands.Add(new SqlCommand(komenda, dostep()));
```

and, of course, before using an object, you need to initialize it with

```
List<SqlCommand> commands = new List<SqlCommand>();
```

As a side note, I am a bit perplexed by your approach to build a list of SqlCommand with the SqlConnection object initialized. This could be a very resource hog if you have many commands.

Comment: +1 for not only providing a solution, but answering the question why the exception was thrown.